# What is the best way to set the followers list using parse.com

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

so i am working on an app where user can follow each other.. i've been working on it and tried to set the followers in a class `Followers` and saved the PFUser.currentUser().objectId in the column `follower` and the objectId of the user in column `user` i am saving the objectId as Strings. Is this the best possible way or we can use something else to achieve the require things easily. Help me out here please. Thanks for your time..

Comment: If you set the column type in Parse to pointer then you can simply assign the PfObject to the column and you don't need to worry about ObjectIds.

Comment: u mean if set `user` as the pointer and `follower` too then it would be easy?

Comment: Yes, almost any time you want to store a reference to another PFObject you will use a pointer or relation type.  You will almost never refer directly to the objectId in Parse.  In your case you could also probably just add a `followers` array to the _User object

Comment: but if we add `followers` array to the _User class then we get an error.. because every user doesn't have the permission to write the objects in User class.

Comment: Ok, then you can use a separate class (but you will still need an array of followers) or a better approach is to create `addFollower` and `removeFollower` cloud code functions so that your business logic executes on the Parse cloud and can make use of the masterkey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the column type to Pointer and then have each Pointer be of type User so that you can link directly to the User objects and query on them.

Comment: but there's a limit to these type of data to query rite??

Comment: I'm not sure what your question means exactly. You will only be able to put User objects in those columns, but that's what you want. Then you can use the includeKey() function to make sure that the followers and users are brought in along with the queries